# How to wait for a server to successfully respond to an HTTP request

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, http, httpwebrequest

I am currently working with an internal API and visual studio (new to both of them). I am trying to submit a GET request to the server which will give me a JSON with the user info. One of the field in the expected JSON response is connect_status which shows true if its connecting and false once the connection is done meaning the response has been received. So far I have been working with the following using Sleep to wait for a bit until getting the response.

```
    bool isConnected;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.ContentType = "application/json"; 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    do
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader info = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        string json = info.ReadToEnd();
        accountInfo user1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<accountInfo>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
        isConnected = user1.connect_status;
    }
    while (isConnected == true);
```

The problem with this is that I have to wait for a longer time, the time it takes is variable and that's why I have to set a higher sleep time. Alsosomeimtes 10 seconds might not be enough and in that case when the do while loop loops the second time I get an exception at while(isConnected==true) saying

> NUllReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

What would be a better/different way of doing this as I don't think the way I am doing is right.

Comment: Are you aware that the request is not sent to the server until you call GetResponse() and that multiple calls to GetResponse() on the same request just return the same response? The request is not re-issued.

Comment: No I wasn't aware of that, thank you for the info! So that would mean that the loop that I am doing wouldn't do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option here, if using .NET 4.5:

```
HttpMessageHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = yourCookieContainer };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) {
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost")
};

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpContent content = new StringContent("dataForTheServerIfAny");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("relativeActionUri", content);
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
accountInfo user1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<accountInfo>(json);
```

This way you let .NET take care of that waiting and such for you.

Comment: I also have a Cookiecontainer, how would I specify that here? So far I have used something like request.CookieContainer=mycookie;

Comment: I also forgot to define content, which I added as well

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! What does relativeActionUri refer to?

Comment: I tried using this but its still giving me a json with not empty values for the parameters and connect_status still shows as true which means it didn't finish processing the request.

Comment: relativeActionUri is basically just appended to the base address before making the call, so if I made a call to http://localhost/api/login, it would be "api/login"

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean about the connect_status. This value is filled in by the server you are making your call to. If it returned anything, that by definition means that your call has completed.

Comment: connect_status should show false meaning that the connection has been completed and the expected json is returned. However in my case(when time is lower) and even in the code you showed, I keep getting connect_status as true and all the other parameter values are blank instead of having a string content.